# Chatting layout in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, chat

as shown in the picture below + xml code, I created this design in chatting.xml, then I created 2 bubbles images by 9-Patch,but my problem is:

How can I put these bubbles images to be the background of the chatting text in this chatting.xml and how can I add the ListView is it important?

chatting.xml

[image: Chatting]

chatting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/MidnightBlue"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_weight=".99"
            android:background="@color/LightGray" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textInput"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:textColor="@color/MidnightBlue" 
                android:text="Send"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Bubble Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Image View for the bubble in chatting.xml. set it's focus to false,             `android:focusable="false"` You'll only want the bubble shown when text is received.
As for the listview, yes you'll need one as you want to be able to format the conversation, say a new row for every message. Create a listview in chatting.xml. The list view should automatically scroll so you don't need the scroll view.

Comment: thanks for answering me, but I tried to drag and drop the listView Wedjet but I couldn't !!! can you explain more thanks alot :"

Comment: replace your scrollview with '<ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="421dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
        </ListView>'

You might have to hard code the bubble image rather than using the xml widget. Do this with a custom adapter, google custom listview adapter